# Controls added dynamically are always removed/deleted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a button dynamically triggered by a button event (not from Page_Load) but the controls added was removed automatically.

```
Protected Sub btnDate_Click(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = CType(s,Button).Text & " has been clicked."
End Sub

Protected Sub btnDiagDateOK_Click(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDiagDateOK.Click

    Dim b As New Button
    Dim dates() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split("|") ' Ex: 10OCT2014|11OCT2014|12OCT2014

    For Each s As String in dates
        b = New Button
        b.Text = s
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf btnDate_Click

        Panel1.Controls.Add(b)
    Next

End Sub
```

The problem is every time I click a different button (or the buttons created), all the controls inside Panel1 are removed.

Is there a way that controls I created will not be removed without using a user defined javascript?

Comment: You need to recreate the controls on each and every postback, and they must have the exact same ID each time. When creating controls on postback, it's best for new controls to exist before the OnLoad event so that they are properly created in time to receive a postback event. Otherwise postback occurs and they don't exist in time to receive any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "user defined javascript".

Every time the page is instantiated on the server, page controls are created based on the markup in page's aspx file. Unless there is code in one of the page methods, the page does not know/remember about additional controls dynamically created in its previous reincarnations. You have to save the information about these controls (for example, in page's ViewState) and create them again in `Page_Load`  at the latest.

Comment: It is similar to Session but it is a bit complicated since I will be using it dynamically. The objects still remain but I have another event that will change the object's properties, trigger by clicking itself. Never thought ViewState would be a great help :)